# How to change a HTML element to DOJO widget programmatically?

Tags: html, dojo, birt, dojox.grid.datagrid, dijit.form

My scenario is as follows:

I'm currently using DOJO framework 1.9, with BIRT reporting tool 4.2. BIRT creates a form element (dynamically) in a page, and all input fields (which are from dojo) comes under this form.
And when I try to validate the form (on submit), I can't do that, since the form is not DOJO form.

So, **is there any way to convert this HTML form to DOJO form (dijit.form) programmatically?**

Or, in general, **Is it possible to change a HTML element to DOJO widget programmatically?**

Answer (score 1):

You can implement both solutions with dojo. You can create a Dojo widget programmatically or declaratively. You can convert any HTML element to DOJO widget programmatically. 
E.g of button created programmatically by Id.

```
<body class="claro">
    <div>
      <!--HTML Button element with id ="btn2"-->
        <button id="btn2"></button>
    </div>
    <script>
        require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button) {
            var button2 = new Button({
                iconClass: "dijitIconNewTask",
                showLabel: false,
                label: "Click Me!", // analogous to title when showLabel is false
                onClick: function(){ console.log("Second button was clicked!"); }
            }, "btn2");//this is the id of HTML element.

            button2.startup();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

[View Programmatic Demo Here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/themes_buttons_textboxes/demo/ProgButton.php)

In the same way you can create any Dojo widget programmatically.

Comment: This will replace the original element. I want to retain the attributes and properties the former one had.
I'm doubting that if this is possible...?